# Semi-opaque background darkening image

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a background image that adds a semi-transparent background on hover. Here's my (simplified) HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="hi.jpg">
</div>
```

Here's how I achieve the semi transparent overlay:

```
.container:hover > .overlay {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .2
}
```

However, when I hover over the container, not only is its background image affected by the black background, so is the image, as though the image were UNDER the overlay background, making it slightly darker. I tried remedying this by setting the image's z index to 3, but it is still darkened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` only works on elements that are positioned, so give your image `position: relative` as well as increasing its `z-index`.